# Setting (click) within *ngFor

Tags: angular

I am looping through v.social and displaying social.icon, social.name and social.url within each . I would like to add a (click) action that includes the social.url parameter but this isn't working:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let social of v.social" (click)="launch('{{ social.url }}')">
    <img src="{{ social.icon }}" item-left class="social-image">
    <p>{{ social.name }}<br>{{ social.url }}</p>        
</ion-item>
```

How can I set the parameter for the launch function to be social.url ?

Comment: Have you tried `(click)="launch(social.url)"`?

Comment: Hero. So simple - why didn't I do that? Thank you.

Comment: You should see the mistakes I do :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ngFor` variable like this:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let social of v.social" (click)="launch(social.url)">
```